# Trouble creating static link using Django template system

Tags: django, django-templates

I am attempting to create a static link to an html file that I will load into an `<a>` tag or an `<iframe>`. Here is how I create the url:

```
{% with '/static/projects/'|add:project.slug|add:'/'|add:f|add:'.html' as banner_static %}
{% static banner_static %}
{% endwith %}
```

This code creates the desired url (/static/projects/project-name/file-name.html), but as soon as I add this to an  tag I get this:

```
<a href="/static/">test</a>
```

Any ideas as to why it is being truncated? Am I not using the django template tag correctly?

Comment: Have you tried with `<a href="{{ banner_static }}">Link</a>`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to run it through the `static` tag in the first place; your link already includes the static prefix.

Comment: <a href="{{ banner_static }}">Link</a> -does work as well, I updated my code to reflect this simpler syntax.

Answer (score 0):

My original plan did work, turned out I had not made sure the '{% static banner_static %}' was properly wrapped by the 'with' loop.